# After upgrading to Node 8.10.0 hash password produces different output

Tags: node.js

I upgraded Node.js version from `6.9.x` to `8.10.0`.  And I noticed that some users can't login with old passwords. I checked reason and seems with `8.10.0` my old code now generates another hash.

I'm sure that problem is related to one of this lines (may be both):

```
this.salt = Buffer.from(crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('base64'), 'base64');
```

or this

```
return crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, new Buffer(this.salt, 'base64'), 10000, 64, 'sha1').toString('base64');
```

I'd read that there was some changes in `Buffer` and `crypto` API, but can't find what exactly brings this problems for me.

How to change my code so it will output same hashes as with Node 6.9.x version?

Comment: refer to this: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/7464